# Автоудаление файла Python c библиотекой pynput

Tags: python, pynput

День добрый. Столкнулся с неизвестной проблемой. Пишу keylogger на python при помощи pynput. Но в какой-то момент файл сам по себе просто удаляется. Это происходит как и в файле, созданном в PyCharm, так и в обычном текстовом документе. Попытался найти информацию об этом, но пусто. Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: Пробовали антивирус отключить?

Comment: @insolor сейчас попробовал, теперь всё работает нормально. Спасибо за ответ.  <3